# How to upgrade jboss seam from 1.1 to 2.0?

Tags: jsf, upgrade, jboss-seam

We have legacy application which uses Jboss seam 1.1. Now we need to move to jboss seam 2.0 as we are moving the app from JSF 1.1 to JSF 1.2 (seam 1.1 supports JSF 1.1 and seam 2.0 supports JSF 1.2).

What are the steps required to do this migration? I looked into their docs and on the net but couldn't find anything which explains this migration.

Answer (score 0):

See ["Chapter 4. Migrating from Seam 1.2 to Seam 2"](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html/Seam_2_Reference_Guide/migration.html) and ["Chapter 2. Migration"](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/Migration.html) in the [Seam Reference Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/).